# How to add <div> in <form> on button click html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add the following div structure whenever the '+' button [the addMore() function] is clicked. Although i am able to add the div structure, but the alignment of the input text are not equal as compared to the hard coded.

html file:

```
<form class="align-center">
            <p class="6u 12u$(medium)">
                    Start Date: <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate" /> 
                    End Date: <input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate" />
            </p>
            <p>
               <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="text" name="numParticipants" id="numParticipants" value="" placeholder="Number of Participants"/></div>
            </p>
            <p>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="3u 12u$(medium)">
                            <div class="select-wrapper">
                                <select>
                                    <option value="">-Select Programme-</option>
                                    <option value="1">Yogalates</option>
                                    <option value="2">Pilates</option>
                                    <option value="3">Kick Boxing</option>
                                    <option value="4">K-Pop Dance</option>
                                    <option value="5">Hip Hop</option>
                                    <option value="6">Jazz Aerobics</option>
                                    <option value="7">Zumba</option>
                                    <option value="8">Fitball</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div>OR</div>
                    <div class="3u 12u$(medium)">
                            <div class="12u$">
                                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Customize your own programme" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="2u 12u$(medium)">
                        <div class="12u$">
                            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Venue" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </p> 
            <p>
                <div class="row" id="newProg">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="2u 12u$(medium)">
                        <a class="button" onclick="addMore()"><div style="font-size: 35px">+</div></a>
                        <a class="button" style="margin:0 0 0 1em" onclick="removeProg()"><div style="font-size: 35px">-</div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="2u 12u$(medium); image right">
                    <a href="#popup1" class="button">Submit</a>
                </div>
            </p>                              
    </form>
```

main.js

```
    var counter = 0;
function addMore() {
        counter++;
        var objNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
        objNewDiv.setAttribute('id', 'addProg' + counter);
        objNewDiv.setAttribute('class', 'row');
        objNewDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="5u 12u$(medium)"> <div class="select-wrapper"> <select> <option value="">-Select Programme-</option> <option value="1">Yogalates</option> <option value="2">Pilates</option> <option value="3">Kick Boxing</option> <option value="4">K-Pop Dance</option> <option value="5">Hip Hop</option> <option value="6">Jazz Aerobics</option> <option value="7">Zumba</option> <option value="8">Fitball</option> </select> </div> </div> <div>OR</div> <div class="5u 12u$(medium)"> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Customize your own programme"/> </div> <div class="3u$ 12u$(medium)"> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Venue" /> </div> ';
        document.getElementById('newProg').appendChild(objNewDiv);
}
```

Result when page is loaded:
[when page loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi23d.jpg)

Actual and Expected result:
[actual and expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZGg3.jpg)

Comment: could you create a SO snippet / fiddle?

Comment: @user7146946 HTML is incomplete. Please do share the entire DIV code.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas shared the entire DIV code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have differenc in the class names of the `div` tags which you are appending in jquery.

Make it same as the Static HTML content, And the expected result will be achieved.

Differences I see is as below.

Static HTML has - `<div class="3u 12u$(medium)">` ,Your Jquery HTML has - `<div class="5u 12u$(medium)">`

Static HTML has - `<div class="3u 12u$(medium)">`, Your jquery HTML has - `<div class="5u 12u$(medium)">`

Static HTml has - `<div class="2u$ 12u$(medium)">`, Your Jquery HTML has `<div class="3u$ 12u$(medium)">`

Because of the differences in the class names you find the differences in the way its rendered in the UI.

Comment: if the class names are the same, the outcome of the input text in the div structure does not have the same size as the one in static HTML

Comment: @user7146946 you already have the `div` with class `row` as your placeholder for new contents, but in your jquery  you are again building a `div` with class `row` So may be thats an issue.. try changing that and check

Answer (score 0):

You missed one of your divs in JavaScript inner HTML string. I think it should be like this:

```
objNewDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="5u 12u$(medium)"> <div class="select-wrapper"> <select> <option value="">-Select Programme-</option> <option value="1">Yogalates</option> <option value="2">Pilates</option> <option value="3">Kick Boxing</option> <option value="4">K-Pop Dance</option> <option value="5">Hip Hop</option> <option value="6">Jazz Aerobics</option> <option value="7">Zumba</option> <option value="8">Fitball</option> </select> </div> </div> <div>OR</div> <div class="5u 12u$(medium)"> <div class="12u$"> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Customize your own programme"/> </div> </div> <div class="3u$ 12u$(medium)"> <div class="12u$"> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Venue" /> </div> </div> ';
```

Comment: added that divs, but the outcome is still the same

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` in CSS for `6u$ 12u$` class. Combined with code from my answer.

Comment: @user7146946 Did you try my ^ comment?